# jquery mouseleave: don't trigger when entering a tip

Tags: jquery, mouseleave, tipsy

Hello my fellow developers,

I have some trouble polishing my UI.

I've made a popup panel, that opens when I hover over a button/link.

this panel should close whether I go out of that button/link or out of the panel itself. Pretty straight forward.

[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hk5ka/5/) (jsFiddle)  I made a simple demonstration, and it works well as expected.

my JS code:

```
$('[data-tip]').tipsy({fade: true, gravity: 's'});

$('#btn').mouseenter(function(e){
  $('#panel').show();
}).mouseleave(function(e){
  var $panel = $('#panel')[0];  
  var $out_el = $(e.relatedTarget)[0];

  if($out_el != $panel){
    $('#panel').hide();
  }
});

$('#panel').mouseleave(function(e){
  var $btn = $('#btn')[0];  
  var $out_el = $(e.relatedTarget)[0];
  var $tipsy = $('.tipsy')[0];

  if($out_el != $btn && $out_el != $tipsy){
    $('#panel').hide();
  }
});
```

and HTML markup

```
<a href="#" id="btn">BUTTON</a>

<div id="panel">
  <a href="#" title="1" data-tip="test 1">Test anchor 1</a>
  <a href="#" title="2" data-tip="test 2">Test anchor 2</a>
</div>
```

The problems are tips. (jquery tipsy plugin to be exact).
In the example I provided I put 2 links inside my popped up panel. Both have a tipsy attached. So on hover a tip is shown. All well.

The problem is that if I touch the tip, the panel closes. I DON'T WANT THAT.
So I added another check on my onmouseleave event... to check if the "leave element" is tipsy...

but the problem (I guess) is that tipsy destroys before my event, so I cannot check if "leave element" is tipsy or not. (for $('.tipsy') I get empty and of course $('.tipsy')[0] is undefined.

please advise!

Comment: The JSFiddle fails for me, in IE console tells me it doesn't know of .tipsy() even though I see you added it as a resorce. In Chrome I don't see any text at all in any JSFiddle. Does it work for you?

Comment: hint: if you remove the `$('#panel').mouseleave` section it doesn't hide when you touch tipsy.

Comment: @Nenotlep: thanks, I corrected, and included tipsy plugin directly in js panel. 

popnoodles: of course not... logically ;)

Comment: i.e. you were overcomplicating it. see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hk5ka/10/)

The condition of your mouseleave is making it hide. Try this instead.

```
$('#panel').mouseleave(function(e){
  if (e.target==this) $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: better solution... more simple and more straight forward. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hk5ka/8/ or same code with tipsy included into JS pane (for IE) http://jsfiddle.net/hk5ka/9/

And here is updated condition for mouse leave:

```
$('#panel').mouseleave(function(e){
  var $btn = $('#btn')[0];  
  var $out_el = $(e.relatedTarget)[0];  

  if($out_el != $btn && (!$(e.toElement).hasClass("tipsy") && $(e.toElement).closest(".tipsy").length == 0)){
    $('#panel').hide();
  }
});
```